# TensorFlow.js returning TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined when loading models

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

Trying to recreate the [emoji scavenger](https://github.com/google/emoji-scavenger-hunt) hunt from google and it returned me the following error:

[image]

Here is my only code that is running at the moment:

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import { loadFrozenModel, FrozenModel } from '@tensorflow/tfjs-converter';

export default class MobileNet {
    constructor() { }

    async load() {
        const MODEL_URL = '/assets/project-gaea/models/web_model.pb';
        const WEIGHTS_URL = '/assets/project-gaea/models/weights_manifest.json';
        const model = await loadFrozenModel(MODEL_URL, WEIGHTS_URL);
        const cat = document.getElementById('cat');
        model.execute({input: tf.fromPixels(cat)});
    }
}
```

Comment: If it works after you downgraded those two packages, then it is a viable solution to the problem. Probably a short term one, but one nevertheless. You could answer your own question with that solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered that the error was being caused by an upgraded version of tfjs-core and tfjs-converter. I downgraded it according to the demo and seems to be working. a long term solution as it still doesnt solve the problem for new developers. Raised it in GitHub too